# Why are my leaves on my royal poincianas turing yellow?

Tags: trees, diseases, leaves

so I started growing my royal poincianas from seeds and I have been noticing that their leaves are starting to turn yellow. I don't know if it was a good idea to put my mom's and and brothers ashes in the soil. I only sprinked a little on top of the soil. I did buy a moisture meter just waiting for it to be picked up at home depot.  I feel that I tend to over water. Not sure how often I should be watering? Any recommendations? Also before I forget on one of my royals, well his roots are starting to show out of the bottom of his pot. Should I put Fred in a bigger pot? Please help these guys are very very special to me. I don't wanna lose them. So any recommendations would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to growing anything. im new to the bonsai world too. Currently they are in 6in pots not sure if I need bigger? Thank you
[image: this is one of my royals fred]

[image: these are freds roots showing]

[image: another angel of fred]

[image: this picture is of my second royal his name is ted he has more yellowing thanfred]

[image: this is my other little guy ted he has lost quite a few of leaves]

[image: this is another angel of teds leaves and the yellowing]